# PHP Code - no idea if it does something

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have the following code snippet, in an appliation working with Zend Framework. I know what Zend Date does.. thats not the problem.

But the coder simply calls "$date" , and i dont know if this does something?

```
         $date = new Zend_Date(time());
         $date->addDay(1);
         $date; 
         // save date, or do something else
         ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't imagine a situation where simply stating a variable, whether it be an object, string, or otherwise, would perform some kind of action. It might just be a mistake.

Comment: `I can't imagine a situation where simply stating a variable, [...] would perform some kind of action.`

Not in PHP, at least :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, it does nothing except using up some CPU cycles.

Comment: in other words, remove it! No point wasting CPU, and no point confusing any more future developers looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it had other use before, like `echo $date;`. Just writing a variable does **absolutely nothing**.

Answer (score 0):

It adds a day to $date. Where is the confusion? The 3rd line does nothing.